# Continuity of discrete probability distributions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, definite-integrals

In  [Information Theory And Statistical Mechanics](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/brandeis.pdf) , when it comes to the derivation of the continuous form of Shannon's entropy, I don't quite understand the first part of the derivation(Eqs.60-62).

> We suppose that the the discrete points $x_i, i = 1,2,...,n$, become more and more numerous, in such a way that, in the limit $n\rightarrow ∞$， the density of points approaches a definite function $m(x)$:
> $$ lim_{n\rightarrow ∞} \frac{1}{n}(number\ of\ points\ in\ a<x<b) = \int_a^bm(x)dx\quad\quad (60) $$

in my opinion, the left side of this equation is the probability of an $x$ falling into the interval $(a,b)$; as for the right side, probably I can take $m(x)$ as some probability density function and the whole integral is also the probability which is consistent with the left side.
However, in [Introduction to  Continuous Entropy](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=cc607d9fd68e2124dc01a9eebcfe31c349a1361c43860219fda1f1f891e0e9ffJmltdHM9MTY1NjUwNDU2MiZpZ3VpZD0yODMxOWM4My1iZDc4LTQ2MWYtYmZiZC01MTIxOGJhODVhM2ImaW5zaWQ9NTE2OQ&ptn=3&fclid=4f49a432-f7a4-11ec-bec9-b0642fd0afe7&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuY3JtYXJzaC5jb20vcGRmL0NoYXJsZXNfTWFyc2hfQ29udGludW91c19FbnRyb3B5LnBkZg&ntb=1)(P6), it says that the function $m(x)$ is actually  not a probability density function but a invariant factor.
So how should I understand this function if I take the result of the left side as a probability?

> If this passage to the limit is sufficiently well behaved, it will also be true that adjacent differences($x_{i+1}-x_{i}$) in the neighborhood of any particular value of $x$ will tend to zero so that
> $$lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}[n(x_{i+1}-x_{i})] = [m(x_i)]^{-1}\quad\quad (61)$$

firstly, why $(x_{i+1}-x_{i})$ tends to zero if the first equation holds, isn't the $x_i$ just the value which $X$ takes? Secondly, how should I understand both sides of this equation?

> The discrete probability distribution $p_i$ will go over into a continuous probability density $w(x)$, according to the limiting form of
> $$p_i = w(x_i)(x_{i+1}-x_{i})\quad\quad (62)$$

because I don't understand the meaning of $(x_{i+1}-x_{i})$ yet, I can not fully understand this equation. However, I do know that if I treat $(x_{i+1}-x_{i})$ as $dx$ then the right side of the equation is a unit probability in discrete sense.

Any reply will be appreciated.